# IE 8 specific bug looking for ideas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unfortunately I can't dump my code here currently as a majority of it is propitiatory based. However I am just looking for ideas on what could cause this issue in a specific version of IE. This code is tested and works in FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE 7, IE 9, but does not and refuses to work in IE 8. And any fixes I attempt to apply will break it on all browsers.

In IE 8 the error is "Expecting '}'" which I know what that should obviously mean. But myself and 3 others have crawled this code from line one all the way down looking for any broken brackets, parentises, or just bad syntax. And other than some miss useage of HTML (this project was handed down to me). I see no issues, as I said all other browsers treat this code fine with no errors as a result.

Anyone have a guess at whats up with IE 8? cause I for one am stumped.

Comment: Man, I can not conclude anything without the code

Comment: Have you tried passing it through something like [JSHint](http://jshint.com)? It may reveal something important.

Comment: have you run your code through http://jslint.com?

Comment: Can't possibly answer this without seeing the code.  Voting to close.

Comment: Trailing comma in an object? Run the code through [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/)

Comment: check that the loops have the bracket just before the parenthesis `for(){` because if it is on other line the automatic semicolon insertion might add one in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time I encounter a missing `}` it has been because I was missing a `}`. So I would guess that is it.

Go back and check again. They are easy to miss.

If you are still stumped, and it wasn't that or you couldn't find it, then perhaps IE8 is somehow commenting one out and you might want to look into that. Not sure if that is the problem or how you could figure that out since there is no code to look at.

Comment: If the code is properly formatted with tabs and carriage returns, it should be easy to spot.  If not, then missing brackets are nearly impossible to see.